# routes with wrong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have the following route:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :events, only: %i[index]
  delete :close_account, on: :member
end
```

for some reason, it generate routes with different params:

```
       GET      /backoffice/users/:user_id/events(.:format)               backoffice/events#index
       DELETE   /backoffice/users/:id/close_account(.:format)             backoffice/users#close_account
```

in one route, the param is `user_id` and the route below is `id`. I wanted both to be `user_id`, so I added `resources :users, param: :user_id`

and now the routes are weirder than before:

```
      GET      /backoffice/users/:user_user_id/events(.:format)          backoffice/events#index
      DELETE   /backoffice/users/:user_id/close_account(.:format)        backoffice/users#close_account
```

how can I fix this routes in such a way that both routes have the same param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are not "wrong". The reason you're seeing this behavior is that the `id` parameter name is here reserved to the innermost resource. That is, if your `EventsController` had some other actions besides `index`, it would receive the event id as `id`, while the related `User` id would be `user_id`. The other route is not a nested resource, and as such has no need for different prefixes.

This can be seen in the [Rails guides section on nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

That being said, if you truly want both to be referred to as `user_id`, you should use

```
delete "/backoffice/users/:user_id/close_account/", to: "backoffice/users#close_account"
```

Comment: I read the guide, but seems like I didn't paid attention to this part specifically :( well, makes total sense! thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is absolutely confusing, I agree. The simplest possible solution which utilizes Rails instrumentation is to use resources twice, one without  specified param name and the other with it:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  resources :events
end
resources :users, param: :user_id
```

In general one would use

```
resources :users, param: :number do
  resources :events
end
resources :users, param: :user_number
```

This will produce

```
GET    /users/:user_number/events(.:format)          /events#index
POST   /users/:user_number/events(.:format)          /events#create
GET    /users/:user_number/events/new(.:format)      /events#new
GET    /users/:user_number/events/:id/edit(.:format) /events#edit
GET    /users/:user_number/events/:id(.:format)      /events#show
PATCH  /users/:user_number/events/:id(.:format)      /events#update
PUT    /users/:user_number/events/:id(.:format)      /events#update
DELETE /users/:user_number/events/:id(.:format)      /events#destroy
GET    /users/new(.:format)                          /users#new
GET    /users/:user_number/edit(.:format)            /users#edit
GET    /users/:user_number(.:format)                 /users#show
PATCH  /users/:user_number(.:format)                 /users#update
PUT    /users/:user_number(.:format)                 /users#update
DELETE /users/:user_number(.:format)                 /users#destroy
```

If you prefer wrapping controllers in the module use scope instead.